# What happens if I don't put "use strict" in a function?

Tags: javascript, use-strict

What's the difference following two cases?

#### Using `use strict` at the top of the file, not in a function

```
"use strict";

(function () {
  // ...
})();
```

#### Using `use strict` in the wrapping function

```
(function () {
  "use strict";
  // ...
})();
```

I read in a [blog post](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/tips-and-practices) that putting `use strict` at the top of the file (not in a function) *could have unforeseen effects*.

Also, from what I remember `jshint` recommends putting it into a function too.

So, why is it better to have it into a function instead of putting it in the top of the file?

Comment: Another dupe – [__Why is 'use strict' usually after an IIFE (rather than at the top of a script)?__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670872/why-is-use-strict-usually-after-an-iife-rather-than-at-the-top-of-a-script/38670885#38670885)

Comment: @Rayon Thanks! But still, I don't get it: why would I enable the strict mode only inside of a function? Isn't it better to use it globally, in the entire file?

Comment: From _docs_, _If you are using strict mode for entire script, it isn't possible to blindly concatenate non-conflicting scripts. Consider concatenating a strict mode script with a non-strict mode script: the entire concatenation looks strict! The inverse is also true: non-strict plus strict looks non-strict. Concatenation of strict mode scripts with each other is fine, and concatenation of non-strict mode scripts is fine._

Comment: @Rayon But supposing I have code written only in strict mode, doest that apply?

Comment: No, bu on many occasions, we use external libraries which may not work under `"strict mode";`

Comment: @Rayon So, `"use strict"` is applied globally across all the loaded files, not only the current file?

Comment: It happens when we concatenate JS files over production...

Comment: @Rayon Ah, got it! Makes sense.